# Laravel Passport API: Retrieve Authenticated Token

Tags: php, laravel, api, token, laravel-passport

## Situation

I'm using Laravel Passport API to communicate between Laravel and external "agents" via Personal Access Tokens: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#personal-access-tokens

You can create multiple tokens per user.

Authentication works and I can retrieve the User via `Auth::User()`

## Question

How can I check which token is used?

## Background

I want to use different tokens for different "agents" for the same user and I need to know which token is used to see who is connecting.

Comment: You should be able to look up the `token`, `user_id` and `client_id` in the `oauth_access_tokens` table. Check out this discussion, too: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passport-rest-makeauth

Comment: You can use Auth::user()->token() function to get token model. This is object of class "Token extends Model" so you should be able to use it like any other model.

Comment: @ElChupacabra Yes that works! Thanks! Can you put this as answer to the question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
Auth::user()->token()
```

function to get token model. This is object of class "Token extends Model" so you should be able to use it like any other model.

In addition in my project I also have that model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OauthAccessToken extends Model
{
    //
}
```

and relation:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    //...
    public function accessTokens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OauthAccessToken');
    }
}
```

So I can simply access all tokens and for example delete them:

```
Auth::user()->accessTokens()->delete();
```

Comment: This answer is pretty good, but can you please tell me exactly how you linked the OauthAccessToken model to the table, or is a trait you can use? Thank you man!

Comment: It's automatically linked if the class name is exact the same as database table. The only difference is that in php you use CamelCase instead of underscored.

Comment: Hello thank you for this just a quick question so how do i get the actual token this is my result  ```  [
    {
        "id": 825786976,
        "user_id": 1,
        "client_id": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "scopes": "[]",
        "revoked": 0,
        "created_at": "2022-02-26T16:58:28.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-26T16:58:28.000000Z",
        "expires_at": "2023-02-26 16:58:28"
    }
]